# googletag dynamically definingslot from API response is not working

Tags: javascript, google-tag-manager, google-publisher-tag

Note : I have masked data for privacy purpose.

I have API response which gives me below information: Also, the API response is dynamic so depending on business requirements I get 2 or 20 ad-slot information.

```
{
"googletags":[
  {
     "networkId":"xyz",
     "targetedAdUnit":"Test_Offers_1",
     "adSlotCreativeSize":[
        [
           336,
           280
        ],
        [
           320,
           100
        ]
     ],
     "divGPTId":"div-gpt-ad-1"
  },
  {
     "networkId":"xyz",
     "targetedAdUnit":"Test_Offers_2",
     "adSlotCreativeSize":[
        [
           336,
           280
        ],
        [
           320,
           100
        ]
     ],
     "divGPTId":"div-gpt-ad-2"
  }
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
{
     "networkId":"xyz",
     "targetedAdUnit":"Test_Offers_n",
     "adSlotCreativeSize":[
        [
           336,
           280
        ],
        [
           320,
           100
        ]
     ],
     "divGPTId":"div-gpt-ad-n"
  }
 ]
}
```

I am using this response and defining slot on runtime.

javascript code:

```
window.googletag = window.googletag || { cmd: [] };
function googleTags(url, cFunction) {
  const xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
      cFunction(this);
    }
  };
  xhttp.open('GET', url, true);
  xhttp.send();
}

function pushGTMtags(xhttp) {
  const tags = JSON.parse(xhttp.responseText)['googletags'];
  window.googletag.cmd.push(function () {
    for (let i = 0; i < tags.length; i++) {
      const str = `/${tags[i].networkId}/${tags[i].targetedAdUnit}`;
      const adSlotCreativeSize = tags[i].adSlotCreativeSize;
      const divGPTId = tags[i].divGPTId;
      window.googletag
        .defineSlot(
          str,
          adSlotCreativeSize,
          divGPTId
        )
        .addService(window.googletag.pubads());
    }
    window.googletag.pubads().enableSingleRequest();
    window.googletag.pubads().collapseEmptyDivs();
    window.googletag.enableServices();
  });
}

googleTags('apiUrl', pushGTMtags);
```

HTML : Think this HTML as dynamically itrating with divGPTId. Below is just one example. I am itrating div's based on API response.length.

```
<div class="slot " id="div-gpt-ad-0">
    <script>
        googletag.cmd.push(function () {
            googletag.display('div-gpt-ad-0');
        });
    </script>
</div>
```

After running above code with actual details, I don't see any code error on browser console. but Also, I am not able to see ads on the page. Am I missing something?

I have tried debugging in the browser I don't get any error.